# Why "much" + adjective is wrong while "much" + comparative is right?

Tags: adverbs

I would like to ask for your opinion on why **much** can not describe a normal adjective while it can describe a comparative form of an adjective.
For instance, the sentence 1, 2 are wrong while 3, 4 are correct.

1. ***I am much happy.***
2. ***He is much clever.***
3. ***I am much happier than you are.***
4. ***He is much cleverer than his brother.***

I feel the sentence 1, 2 are weird and 3, 4 are natural. I get it. But, I would like to get any logical explanations on what would make that happen. I would appreciate any assumptions as well.

Comment: The absolute is not a matter of degree.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you for the comment.:) Do you mean that the adjectives in the sentence 1,2 are the absolute which doesn't have the quality of degree and that ***much*** can only describe an expression with a matter of degree? May I ask you explain it a little bit more? :)

Comment: This is not answered by saying that the absolute is not a matter of degree. Because it's fine to say *I am* ***very*** *happy* and *I am* ***only a little bit*** *happy*. But if we can't say *I am* ***much*** *happy* because **happy** implies an absolute, then we also shouldn't be able to use **very** or **a litttle bit** in front of it. Except we can. We can also say *I am* ***much more*** *happy*. There's something else going on here.

Comment: *How* to use **much** is discussed here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers. However, it doesn't explain *why*.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you so much for all the kind **explanations** (or does it have to be just **explanation**? Does it have to be singular or plural or uncountable? Sorry for this absurd another question.) I have read the web page of the link you gave but as you said, there is no reason stated. Would you suggest your any conjecture on why, please?

Comment: Don't get wrapped up in the notion of happiness. This isn't about happiness *per se* but about the assertions, the predications. To say **I am happy** is to state things in absolute terms. To say **I am very happy** or  **I am much happier now** is to state things in relative terms.  Adjectival quantifier **much** has no place in an absolute assertion.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you for the awesome comment as always. I understand what you have explained. Can I put your explanations as in the following by slightly changing them for me to understand easier? ***Much** describes quantity. Normal adjectives like **happy** is an asserted description of a certain quality which is very irrelevant to a notion of quantity, such that they can not be modified by the adverb version of **much**. But the statements in relative terms using comparative adjectives is accompanied by the room for the described quality to have a quantified level on how more the quality is.*

Comment: **much is used for comparisons**: much happier, much richer, much nicer [than before]. This is really very easy and I could not make it much easier [than this]. I don't understand why nobody pointed it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because if you were adding 'Much' in front of 'happy', the normal quantity of happiness increases to an excessive quantity, so it is odd just to write 'Much happy', but 'much happier' does make sense.

> I am very happy.
>
> I am only a little bit happy.

However, in the both cases, it is fine not to change 'happy' to 'happier', because 'very' and 'only a little bit' does not make the quantity of happiness above the normal level, but the lower level in the latter case and just emphasizing 'happy' in the former case, so both do make sense.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I think your answer sounds plausible but I cannot get it perfectly. For the first, I cannot just get that "much" is greater than "very" in terms of the level of the meaning.

Comment: @Smart Humanism "Very" is just emphasizing the quantity of 
happiness, as it is, but "Much" is increasing the quantity of happiness, so "Happy" doesn't have to be "Happier" when modified by "Very" unlike "Much".

Comment: While you are correct about "very happier" not being correct, there's nothing wrong with "only a little bit happier"; it describes a small difference in happiness.